# Kmeans: Wrong size of clusters

Tags: r, k-means

I am running Kmeans algorithm in R on  [Heart Disease UCI](https://www.kaggle.com/ronitf/heart-disease-uci) dataset. I am supposed to get 2 clusters with 138 165 size for each like what in the data set.

Steps:

1. Store dataset in a data frame:

```
df <- read.csv(".../heart.csv",fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM")
```

2. Extract the features:

```
features = subset(df, select = -target)
```

3. Normalize it:

```
normalize <- function(x) {
  return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
}

features = data.frame(sapply(features, normalize))
```

4. Run the algorithm:

```
set.seed(0)
cluster = kmeans(features, 2)
cluster$size
```

Output:

```
[1]  99 204
```

Why?

Comment: A variety of reasons could be responsible for why you are not getting the same clusters. For example, your `set.seed` could be different between your current iteration and your previous iteration. In addition, sorting the data differently plays a role in how the starting point based on the seed is "picked" (for the lack of a better term).

Comment: So is there any thing I can do to get a better result except changing the seed? should I specify ```nstart``` for ```kmeans``` function?

Comment: There are a few things you should consider. Try multiple seeds (I've tried up to 20). Try multiple `nstarts`. Use a combination of the two. I know it isn't an easy solution. Also, has the data changed? Do you have the original results? You may be able to get close to the original by comparing your new run with the original results.

Comment: Data is constant. I am only importing and normalizing it. It has the original results in "target" column, so how can I get close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're focusing on the size of the clusters rather than the accuracy of your predictions. You may well get two clusters of size (138, 165) but not necessarily the same clusters as the 'target' column in the data.

A better way of judging performance is the accuracy of your predictions. In your case, your model accuracy is 72%. You can see this by:

```r
df$label <- cluster$cluster -1

confusionMatrix(table(df$target, df$label))

#Confusion Matrix and Statistics
#   
#      0   1
#  0  76  62
#  1  23 142
#                                          
#               Accuracy : 0.7195 
# ...
```

I was able to get a better accuracy by standardizing the data rather than normalizing. Possibly because standardizing is more robust to outliers.

I also dummy-coded the categorical looking variables which seems to have improved the accuracy. We now have 85% accuracy and the cluster size is closer to what we expect (143 160). Although, as discussed, on its own the cluster size is meaningless.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(fastDummies)
library(caret)
standardize <- function(x){
  num <- x - mean(x, na.rm=T)
  denom <- sd(x, na.rm=T)

  num/denom
}

# dummy-code and standardize
features <-  select(df, -target) %>%
   dummy_cols(select_columns = c('cp','thal', 'ca'),
              remove_selected_columns = T,remove_first_dummy  = T) %>%
  mutate_all(standardize)

set.seed(0)
cluster <- kmeans(features, centers = 2, nstart = 50)

cluster$size
# 143 160

# check predictions vs actual labels
df$label <- cluster$cluster -1

confusionMatrix(table(df$target, df$label))
#Confusion Matrix and Statistics
#
#   
#      0   1
#  0 117  21
#  1  26 139
#                                          
#               Accuracy : 0.8449
```

Of course, there are other accuracy metrics worth considering too such as out-of-sample accuracy (split your data into training and test sets, and calculate accuracy of predictions on your test set), and f1-score.

Comment: what's the difference between "dummy-coded" and not including them in ```features```?

Comment: when we dummy code `thal` we end up with a column for thal=6 (1 or 0), and column for thal = 7 (1 or 0). We don't need the column for thal=3 as that is the case when thal_6 = 0 and thal_7=0, so we remove that column (`remove_first_dummy=T`). The benefit of dummy coding is that gives our variable a meaning (Thal = 3 means 'normal'). Otherwise our variable would be interpreted as numeric which it is not (a value of 4 is meaningless). If we didn't include them at all in `features` we would lose valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that should help you get things straightened out.

```
library(tidyverse)  # data manipulation
library(cluster)    # clustering algorithms
library(factoextra) # clustering algorithms & visualization

df <- USArrests
df <- na.omit(df)
df <- scale(df)


distance <- get_dist(df)
fviz_dist(distance, gradient = list(low = "#00AFBB", mid = "white", high = "#FC4E07"))



k2 <- kmeans(df, centers = 2, nstart = 25)
str(k2)

fviz_cluster(k2, data = df)

 [![enter image description here][1]][1]

k3 <- kmeans(df, centers = 3, nstart = 25)
k4 <- kmeans(df, centers = 4, nstart = 25)
k5 <- kmeans(df, centers = 5, nstart = 25)

# plots to compare
p1 <- fviz_cluster(k2, geom = "point", data = df) + ggtitle("k = 2")
p2 <- fviz_cluster(k3, geom = "point",  data = df) + ggtitle("k = 3")
p3 <- fviz_cluster(k4, geom = "point",  data = df) + ggtitle("k = 4")
p4 <- fviz_cluster(k5, geom = "point",  data = df) + ggtitle("k = 5")

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, nrow = 2)




set.seed(123)

# function to compute total within-cluster sum of square 
wss <- function(k) {
  kmeans(df, k, nstart = 10 )$tot.withinss
}

# Compute and plot wss for k = 1 to k = 15
k.values <- 1:15

# extract wss for 2-15 clusters
wss_values <- map_dbl(k.values, wss)

plot(k.values, wss_values,
       type="b", pch = 19, frame = FALSE, 
       xlab="Number of clusters K",
       ylab="Total within-clusters sum of squares")

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


set.seed(123)

fviz_nbclust(df, kmeans, method = "wss")




# Compute k-means clustering with k = 4
set.seed(123)
final <- kmeans(df, 4, nstart = 25)
print(final)

fviz_cluster(final, data = df)
```

[image]

https://uc-r.github.io/kmeans_clustering